# How to install applications on Linux / Ubuntu without software center

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I've installed applications with the ubuntu software center and even with terminal comands but sometimes I seem to only be able to use applications by downloading a tar.gz file from the vendor website.

Sometimes when I right click on the tar.gz folder it allows me to open in the software center but more often are not I need to extract the tar.gz & open a file which runs the application.

1. What is the correct process for installing applications from a tar.gz folder?
2. Where should I place the contents of the extracted tar.gz folder?
3. Should I be using get apt instead

**UPDATE**

As @Theolodis suggested I ran the below code in my terminal

```
navicat110_mysql_en:$ pwd
/home/ross/Downloads/navicat110_mysql_en
navicat110_mysql_en:$ ls
LGPLV2  Navicat  start_navicat  wine  wine_old
navicat110_mysql_en:$ ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
navicat110_mysql_en:$ ./start_navicat
```

Navicat launched after I ran the last command.

I don't like keeping this applications files in my Download folder, should I put them in my `/bin` directory or my `/home/ross/bin` directory?  What's the correct convention?

Answer (score 1):

```
$tar -xzf file.tar.gz
$cd file
$./configure
$make all
$make install
```

**Most** packages have a configure script which configures the project in an appropriate way to install it directly.

Usually the best approach of achieving a correct installation is to **read the readme file** in the .tar.gz archieve.

And you are not required to install an executable to actually execute it. If you want to have it somewhere where you can call it on the console by typing the name of the executable, you need to place it in some folder that is in the `$PATH`. Under Ubuntu the `$HOME/bin` directory fulfills this requirement, but you could aswell modify/extend the path by extending the file `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.profile`

If you do have an executable file in .tar.gz file, that you want to "install", then I personally use the following way:

```
$mv /tmp/folder /home/user/programs
$cd /home/user/bin
$ln -s /home/user/programs/executable <name>
```

that way you do have a "installed" executable with the name .

If you do need a script to start the program, I usually follow this pattern:

```
$mv /tmp/folder /home/user/programs
$cd /home/user/bin
$vim <name>
$chmod +x <name>
```

but you can use any editor instead of vim to generate the start-stript.

But keep in mind that a program placed in `$HOME/bin` is **installed for the user only**. If you need to *install it for **all** users*, then you should probably place the link to the executable/the start script in `/bin/` and place the unpacked folder with the program files in a *local directory* like `/etc/` or `/opt/`.

Comment: Thank you @Theolodis , unfortunately neither of the of applications I'm trying to install have a configure file. I can start them by running one of their files. Should I put the entire application folder into the $HOME/bin directory? I don't see any sub directories in the $HOME/bin directory. I'll update your question with my terminal output.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was only able to run applications from the extracted directory of the application tar.gz download.

But I found a useful trick to be able to run the ubuntu launcher by creating a .desktop file in the `home/.local/share/applications` directory.  Below are two examples:

**example 1:** `home/.local/share/applications/navicat110_mysql_en.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=11
Type=Application
Name=Navicat
Exec=bash /home/ross/bin/navicat110_mysql_en/start_navicat %f
Icon=/home/ross/bin/navicat110_mysql_en/navicat.png
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
```

**example 2:** `home/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PhpStorm
Icon=/home/ross/bin/PhpStorm-133.982/bin/webide.png
Exec="/home/ross/bin/PhpStorm-133.982/bin/phpstorm.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-phpstorm
```

Just be sure to change the path to your own path for the downloaded & extracted application.